# Subsurface making different shape to the mesh

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have made a crack shape mesh. I want to make that crack wrap around the sphere. I Need to add subsurface modifier a curve and shrinkwrap modifier. The problem is getting when i add subsurface modifier the surface getting odd shape from the original. Any suggestion or help Thanks
[image]

**Original Shape** 
[image]

**After adding subsurface modifier**
[image]

Comment: try not using ngons: eg, convert all faces to triangles.

Comment: @m.ardito Great Thanks it work. Going to next step to shrinkwrap with the curve

Comment: @m.ardito making the triangles faces it work can u make it as a answer Thanks

Comment: you could answer yourself, so you can put the result, and explain others what you did...